# Trying to create td with rowspan

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a `td` with `rowspan`.

I have to create a table with 6 columns from the second column the user has to set the rowspan .

For example:

```
column 2 row1 column3 row1
column 2 row2 column3 row1
column 2 row3 column3 row1
```

```
function addRow() {

    var myName = document.getElementById("namez");
    var age = document.getElementById("age");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="txtbox1[]" />';
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="txtbox2[]" />';
    var td3 = row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="txtbox3" />';
    td3.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2');
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem...?

Comment: Basically: `var a = b = "string";` is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

> `insertCell` will return `cell element`. In your case `td3` will be `'<input type="text" name="txtbox3" />'` and you can not use `setAttribute` over `string`

```js
var td3 = row.insertCell(3);
td3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="txtbox3" />';
td3.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2');
```

Comment: its working but it has a side effect e its creating unwanted columns at the rigth side of the table

Comment: var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="txtbox1[]" value="'+myName.value+'" />';
    var td2=row.insertCell(2);
            
    td2.innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="txtbox2[]" />';
    //td2.setAttribute('rowSpan', '3');
    
    var td3 = row.insertCell(3);
    td3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="txtbox3" />';    
    td3.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2');
    row.appendChild(td3);

Comment: i have tried appendchild but still its adding columns at the right side of the table row.appendChild(td3);

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8vwwkL5L/5/  checkout the code in fiddle its creating more columns on the right side of the table , iam trying to discover why

Comment: Unable to understand your problem. You have 3 columns in the header and you are inserting 4 cells to it..

Comment: i am adding 4 cells the third as the rowspan the problem is that its adding a 5th cell , is this a bug?

Comment: I guess you should use `colspan`. Not sure what you are expecting..Current code is working as it is suppose to..